# Вопрос про FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL

Tags: php

Скажите, почему FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL не приводит следующий email в вид: mail@mail.com?

```
filter_var("mail!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~@.[]@mail.com", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Вернёт mail!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~@.[]@mail.com
```

Почему данный фильтр намеренно оставляет символы !#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~@.[], ведь они не могут быть составной частью корректно написанного адреса?

Comment: Потому что в документации написано что FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL `Remove all characters except letters, digits and !#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~@.[]`

Comment: @InDevX я в курсе на счёт документации. Я хотел узнать, в чём смысл данного фильтра, если он не даёт на выходе валидный email адрес?

Comment: Напишите свою функцию, которая на выходе будет давать валидный имейл